# How to deploy ASP.Net Web API (.Net 4.7.2) using github action

Tags: .net, github, asp.net-web-api, github-actions

I have a ASP.Net Web API that's currently running on .Net 4.7.2 and I want to use Github action for continuous integration but i have no idea how to create a build artifact and upload it to azure. Below you can see my current steps and I have the restore and build process setup, All i need right now is to publish it to azure.

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: setup-msbuild
    uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1
  
  - name: Setup Nuget.exe for use with actions
    uses: Nuget/Setup-nuget@v1.0.2
        
  - name: Restore Nuget Packages
    run: nuget restore solution.sln
    
  - name: Build Solution
    run: msbuild solution.sln
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're targeting 4.7.2 instead of 4.8.1?

Comment: Hi @Dai, project is kinda old and I haven't upgraded yet to 4.8.1.  and I'm trying to publish it with the current .net framework if possible, but if i need to upgrade to 4.8.1 to publish it I think it's not a big issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, adding this additional parameter in msbuild solution.sln

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:PublishUrl="../_build"
```

will create the build artifacts then calling this action

```
  - name: Upload Artifact
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1.0.0
    with:
      name: Bundle
      path: "./_build"
```

to upload the build artifact then adding the azure web-app deploy

```
  - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: 'web-app'
      publish-profile: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
      package: ./_build
```

will automatically deploy it to azure.